# serial postgresql to autonumber access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have a MS Access front end to Postgresql.

I set a serial for a primary key in Postgres.

MS Access has problems inserting or updating data.

How do I make an autonumber in postgres (serial) which access can access.

Comment: You meet the conditions here [Using MS Access with PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/24-Using-MS-Access-with-PostgreSQL.html), especially Access knows the PK and you have `Row Versioning` on.